# Select values from R dataframe column

Tags: r, tidyr

I'm working on a class project using a Chicago crime data set and R. One of the attributes in the data set is `Block` which contains partial addresses where the incident occurred. For example:

```
+--------------------------+
|           Block          |
+--------------------------+
|  45xx N Locust Grove St  |
|   65xx Hawthorne Ave     |
+--------------------------+
```

The values in `Block` vary in length but I am wanting to create a new variable with the street type, St, Ave, Blvd, etc. I have tried using the separate function from tidyr.

```
df <- df %>%
   separate(Block, into = c("partial.address, "type"),
           sep = " ", extra = "merge", fill = "left")
```

However, this returns the number, 45xx, as the `partial.address` value and the remaining value is in `type`. How can I select the street type from the address?

I'm hoping to get something like this as output:

```
+--------------------------+-------------+
|     partial.address      |     type    |
+--------------------------+-------------+
|  45xx N Locust Grove     |      St     |
|   65xx Hawthorne         |     Ave     |
+--------------------------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `extract` :

```
tidyr::extract(df, Block, c("partial.address", "type"), "(.*)(St|Ave)")

#      partial.address  type
#1 45xx N Locust Grove    St
#2      65xx Hawthorne   Ave
```

Or using `stringr` :

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>%
  mutate(type = str_extract(Block, '(St|Ave)'), 
         partial.address = str_remove(Block, type))
```

You can include more patterns in `(St|Ave)` if you have more.

---

If we want to capture the last word of each `Block` we can use :

```
df %>%
  mutate(type = str_extract(Block, '\\w+$'), 
         partial.address = str_remove(Block, type))
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Block = c("45xx N Locust Grove St", "65xx Hawthorne Ave"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Comment: Is there not a way to split on the white space and select the index for the last position to fill the variable type? The data set is 15,000 records and there are several street types.

Comment: @miguelf88 See updated answer. It selects the last word in each `Block`.

Comment: Thanks @RonakShah. Using the str_extract with '\\w+$' worked. I tried using '(St|Ave|Blvd|Rd)' but the column was filled with NA values.